# Correct using double-check idiom

Tags: java, multithreading

```
public class Generator {
private static final Map<byte[], byte[]> cache = new HashMap<byte[], byte[]>();

public static byte[] generate(byte[] src) {
    byte[] generated = cache.get(src);
    if (generated == null) {
        synchronized (cache) {
            generated = cache.get(src);
            if (generated == null) {
                generated = doGenerate(src);
                cache.put(src, generated);
            }
        }
    }
    return generated;
}

private static byte[] doGenerate(byte[] src) {...}
```

}

Can anybody answer, what's wrong in this code?
Maybe generate() method can return partially constructed array, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a start, you are using the `HashMap` unsynchronised. This can lead to, say, infinite loops (this is real - it has been observed in production environments).

It also suffers from the general double-checked locking bug of not having a *happens-before* relationship from writing the contents of the array to reading from it (I am assuming there will be some data).

(Note, you are comparing object identities here, not array contents.)

Another problem is that you have mutable statics, which is poor design that causes serious problems.

Comment: But in HashMap I use only get() method whitout synchronize. Can I get incorrect data from HashMap?(put() placing in synchronized block and any changes must fetch in a main memmory when synchronized block is finished)

Comment: @artem, if the put() changes the map's internal structures while the get() is using those, the get() can fail like Tom described. (all use of the map must be synchronised.)

Comment: Could you tell me more, what can go wrong. I can't understand this. I think at the worst case HashMap return null...

Comment: I don't think this example suffers from the "general" double-checking bug, as `synchronize` establishes a happens-before relationship (according to this: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/memory.html)

Comment: @artem put modifies the internal structures used by map, until it finished executing they will be in an unknown state. It may change references, resize arrays, change index and size values. So you can get Nullpointer, ArrayOutOfBounds and many more exceptions. It could also return wrong values, that all depends on the internal implementation.

Comment: It's worse when the map is being resized. Believing that you don't need to lock when reading is a common mistake. Also believing that the consequences will be minor.

Comment: @Arian - The fast case doesn't enter the `synchronized` block. Therefore, no *happens-before*.

Comment: Bottom line: cache.get() and cache.put() can be called concurrently (you'll spot it if you stare at it for a few seconds). This is worse than a normal double-checked locking pattern. Bad things can happen from ConcurrentModificationExceptions, infinite loops, incorrect results, etc.

Comment: @Tom - If no happens-before is established, execution will enter the synchronized block, thus creating the hb-relation. The "usual" double-checking bug returns uninitialized instances due to an optimization of the `new` operator. This can never happen in artem's case.

Comment: @Arian *happens-before* is a relationship between operations. It makes no sense to say there is a *happens-before* relationship for a single operation (entering a synchronised block).

Comment: I meant the hb-relation between `cache.put` in one thread and `cache.get` in a second thread. If cache.get returns `null` in the second thread, it will enter the synchronized block and then definetly will get the result that was created by the first thread. DCL causes no problems here. If you disagree, please explain exactly how a bug might occur.

Comment: @Arian If the second thread does not return `null` then there is no *happens-before* relationship between the two threads and we have a race.

Comment: If `cache.get` returns a value for the second thread, this means the first thread has already stored this value in the cache. If the data was stored in the cache, it was properly generated and initialized before. It is possible that the second thread returns first from `generate`, but there is no way the second thread can get access to invalid data.

Comment: @Arian No. It doesn't work like that at all. In order for an operation to occur before another in a different thread you need a *happens-before*. The order of events observed/performed in one thread is not necessarily the same as that in another, without the *happens-before*.

Answer (score 3):

Replace your HashMap with ConcurrentHashMap.

Your synchronization looks not useful. I would rewrite the whole thing in this way:

```
private static final Map<byte[], byte[]> cache = new ConcurrentHashMap<byte[], byte[]>();

public static byte[] generate(byte[] src, int counter) {
    byte[] generated = cache.get(src);
    if (generated == null) {
        generated = doGenerate(src);
        cache.put(src, generated);
    }        
    return generated;
}
```

**Edit:** The try/catch was bizarre and not necessary. For the OP's purposes, it suffices to use a ConcurrentHashMap. If the OP really doesn't want to suffer the costs of calling doGenerate twice for the same dataset, then they will have to continue with the DCL pattern, but use of a ConcurrentHashMap is still recommended.

Comment: In that particular code, it's not the potential overhead of generating the value which is the main concern. You may end up getting different values for the same key. (`putIfAbsent` is helpful here. Certainly don't use broken double-checked locking.)

Comment: The original answer/code is misleading. ConcurrentHashMap MUST be used with putIfAbsent() as mentioned by @TomHawtin-tackline

Answer (score 0):

While one thread is executing line 11, another thread may be executing line 5. This is why you need a synchronized map here, and why when using an unsynchronized HashMap your results will be indeterminate.

The solution here is a synchronized Map (see java.util.Collections#synchronizedMap). Of course, if you use a wholly synchronized map then your double-checked locking (extra optimization) becomes redundant.

Comment: Could you please tell me more in details what can go wrong. I think in a worst case generate() can return null... or it can return partially constructed array or array with inconsistent date, isn't it?

Comment: The side effects are implementation specific - the contract is what's important here, and that contract requires that where many threads access a HashMap, and at least one thread changes the content, the access MUST be synchronized. 

A ConcurrentModificationException would be perfectly a perfectly valid result.

From the API docs: "If multiple threads access a hash map concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the map structurally, it must be synchronized externally."